# VS create project does not show no solution

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

It's really bad, my computer is malfunctioning. I reinstalled the asp.net core environment and encountered this problem. What do I need to do?

> Solution 'WebApplication1'(0 projects)

I reinstalled vs according to the online statement, but it didn't work.

Comment: Should there be projects in that solution?  If the solution file itself has changed, you should be able to revert to a known working version in source control.  (If you're not using source control, consider this a lesson learned.  Always use source control.)  Failing that, can you just right-click on the solution and re-add each existing project to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use VS to create the project when this appeared? You try to use the command:

`dotnet --list-sdks`, if the command does not work, please check whether you have installed asp.net core sdk. There is also the simplest way, you download the asp.net core sdk version directly, and then see if the uninstall button pops up during installation, if there is, there may be a problem with the installation, click uninstall and reinstall to create normally project.

For more methods, please refer to this post, which may help you:

[Visual Studio Solution shows (0 projects)](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961210/visual-studio-solution-shows-0-projects)

Comment: Thanks for your help again! ! I uninstalled and reinstalled it and it worked.