# VS2022 just creates empty Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, solution

I just installed V2022 from the Online installer (community) and when I try creating a project in C# winform using.net6 I get nothing! No project No form,no debug and I can not add anything to it

[image]

try to repair it, but it didn't work
Winform project with .net4.8 is OK! but .net 6 and 7.
Why is the solution empty? and debug button is changed to attach !

edit: I also deleted ComponentModelCache folder and nothing changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961210/visual-studio-solution-shows-0-projects

Comment: Try what Hans posted, but you are not the first user to post about this for VS 2022.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks,it was system variable problem