# After updating Visual Studio 2022 "Run button" changed to "Attach to a process". How can I fix this issue?

Tags: visual-studio

After updating Visual Studio 2022 "Run button" changed to "Attach to a process". I tried a lot but can't fix this.

[How can I fix this issue?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhJmY.jpg)

I've followed many tutorials and checked Microsoft forums. I want to fix this issue as soon as possible because my project is ongoing.

Comment: Click on the small v arrow and see if it offers other options.

Comment: 0 projects loaded, that's not good.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74871003/visual-studio-solution-explorer-not-showing-projects-in-solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961210/visual-studio-solution-shows-0-projects

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187471/visual-studio-2022-community-project-not-load-solu